# Pandas truth value of series ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to set one column in a dataframe in pandas based on whether another column value is in a list.
I try:

```
df['IND']=pd.Series(np.where(df['VALUE'] == 1 or df['VALUE'] == 4, 1,0))
```

But I get: Truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
What is the best way to achieve the functionality:

```
If VALUE is in (1,4), then IND=1, else IND=0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `else` value and then modify it with a mask using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
df['IND'] = 0
df.loc[df['VALUE'].isin([1,4]), 'IND'] = 1
```

For multiple conditions, you can do as follow:

```
mask1 = df['VALUE'].isin([1,4])
mask2 = df['SUBVALUE'].isin([10,40])

df['IND'] = 0
df.loc[mask1 & mask2, 'IND'] = 1
```

Consider below example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'VALUE': [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
})
```

Output:

```
    VALUE
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   3
5   3
6   4
7   4
```

Then,

```
df['IND'] = 0
df.loc[df['VALUE'].isin([1,4]), 'IND'] = 1
```

Output:

```
    VALUE   IND
0   1        1
1   1        1
2   2        0
3   2        0
4   3        0
5   3        0
6   4        1
7   4        1
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me if it is possible to add multiple conditions: VALUE is in 1,4 and SUBVALUE is in 7,8

Comment: Thank you. IS it possible to only have a boolean output ? Or can I have an o/p with 3 categories:1,0,'-1' (-1 stands for bad data)

Comment: Can you ask a separate question for that?